# How can I make this Lua script more reliable?

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech-gaming-software

So I've been trying to make my Lua scripts in LogitechGHUB better so that they don't skip a few shots or stop working all of a sudden for a couple of seconds, originally I made this code but no matter what I did it still failed at random moments

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
 if IsKeyLockOn(LockKey)then
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(RC) then 
                repeat 
                           if IsMouseButtonPressed(LC) then 
             repeat                 
                     MoveMouseRelative(0,11)
                     if (coun2<2 and IsMouseButtonPressed(LC))
                     then 
                         MoveMouseRelative(3,13)
                         end
                     if (coun2>10 and coun2<25 and IsMouseButtonPressed(LC))
                     then 
                         MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
                         end
                     if (coun2>35 and coun2<55 and IsMouseButtonPressed(LC))
                     then 
                         MoveMouseRelative(1,0)
                         end
                      if (coun2>65 and coun2<75 and IsMouseButtonPressed(LC))
                     then 
                         MoveMouseRelative(1,1)
                         end
                     if (coun2>85 and IsMouseButtonPressed(LC))
                     then 
                         MoveMouseRelative(1,1)
                         end    
                     Sleep(1)
                     coun2 = coun2+1
             until not IsMouseButtonPressed(LC)
             coun2=0
         end  

                 until not IsMouseButtonPressed(RC)
                end
end
end
LockKey="numlock"                       
coun2 = 0
LC=1                                        
RC=3
```

I changed the idea of using counters to make it more customizable, for loops like this

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)

   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
      for i = 1, 2 do
         MoveMouseRelative(3,20)
         Sleep(1)
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end
      end
      
      for i = 1, 135 do
         MoveMouseRelative(1,12)
         Sleep(1)
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end
      end
end
end
```

Which did in fact make it more consistent as long as I didn't use too many for loops, but it still occasionally stops moving the mouse for random periods of time. I tried changing the Sleep() functions for FastSleep() that I saw another user recommending, but it remained the same just faster. Is there a way of making the script less bound to fail or like something I'm not understanding that messes the code? Or should I simply try a different coding language?

Comment: you probably want to increase the sleep times to a reasonable value. 1ms is nonsense. how is your mouse button supposed to switch state within a millisecond? think about what 1/1000 second means when it comes to humans, movements. especially in non-realtime environment. also you should explain what your script is supposed to do and what exactly makes you think it fails. I mean we're talkin about something that happens within a few milliseconds here.

Comment: I'll try and change that, initially I used higher sleep times but I thought that was the cause of its failing. By failing here I'm referring to not pulling down the mouse when the left click is down, like from time to time it doesn't do its intended purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
local LockKey = "numlock"                       

local moves = {  -- dx/msec, dy/msec, msec
   {0.3, 2.0, 30},
   {0.0, 1.1, 100},
   {0.0, 1.2, 150},
   {0.0, 1.1, 100},
   {0.1, 1.1, 200},
   {0.0, 1.1, 100},
   {0.1, 1.2, 100},
   {0.0, 1.1, 100},
   {0.1, 1.2, math.huge},
}

local function get_distance(t)
   local x, y = 0, 0
   for _, move in ipairs(moves) do
      local vx, vy, mt = move[1], move[2], move[3]
      if t < mt then
         mt = t
      end
      x, y = x + vx*mt, y + vy*mt
      t = t - mt
      if t <= 0 then break end
   end
   return math.floor(x), math.floor(y)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 
      and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsKeyLockOn(LockKey) 
   then
      local t0 = GetRunningTime()
      local t = t0
      repeat
         Sleep(10)
         local oldx, oldy = get_distance(t - t0)
         t = GetRunningTime()
         local newx, newy = get_distance(t - t0)
         MoveMouseRelative(newx - oldx, newy - oldy)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again, but do you know what does the error ` [string "LuaVM"]:18: attempt to index a number value (local 'move') Line Number:1 `
mean? I probably should've edited something to make it work but I was honestly lost when you sent that

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake.  Fix: `for _, move in ipairs(moves) do`